# Filesize of dockerimage doubles with different python version as baseimage

Tags: python, docker, pip, apt

I build dockerimages for a jupyterlab with some apt and pip packages.

```
docker image ls:
jupyterlab    3.7.12     9d4cc5c15853   27 minutes ago   2.3GB
jupyterlab    3.9.9      1962a1eb6bff   25 hours ago     1.12GB
```

The filesize of the images differs quite much, I only took a another python version.

Here are the dockerfiles for comparison:
This dockerfile is build with python 3.7.12 as baseimage:

```
FROM python:3.7.12-slim-buster

WORKDIR /

COPY wheels/scipy-1.7.3-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl ./wheels/scipy-1.7.3-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl

## INSTALL WITH APK
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    g++ \
    gcc \
    python3-dev \ 
    libjpeg-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    make \
    wget \
    libatlas-base-dev \
    libffi-dev 

## INSTALL WITH PIP
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir pillow && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir matplotlib && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir pandas && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir setuptools && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir cffi && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir GLIBC && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir numpy && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir /wheels/scipy-1.7.3-cp37-cp37m-linux_armv7l.whl && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir jupyterlab
    # pip install --no-cache-dir /wheels/numpy-1.21.4-cp39-cp39-linux_armv7l.whl && \
    # pip install --no-cache-dir /wheels/scipy-1.7.2-cp39-cp39-linux_armv7l.whl && \
    # pip install --no-cache-dir /wheels/jupyterlab-4.0.0a15-py3-none-any.whl 
    ...
```

This is the one with python 3.9.9 as baseimage:

```
FROM python:3.9.9-slim-buster

WORKDIR /

COPY wheels ./wheels

## INSTALL WITH APK
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    g++ \
    gcc \
    python3-dev \ 
    libjpeg-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    make \
    wget \
    libatlas-base-dev \
    libffi-dev 

## INSTALL WITH PIP
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir pillow && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir matplotlib && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir pandas && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir setuptools && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir cffi && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir GLIBC && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir /wheels/numpy-1.21.4-cp39-cp39-linux_armv7l.whl && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir /wheels/scipy-1.7.2-cp39-cp39-linux_armv7l.whl && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir /wheels/jupyterlab-4.0.0a15-py3-none-any.whl 
    ...
```

The wheels folder and some other files are deleted in both cases. **Why is there such a big difference in filesize???**

Comment: The 3.7.12 installs an unnamed version of jupyterLab but the 3.9.9 one installs a named version (4.0.0) so I suspect that is the difference? Other than that ... the installed versions are different in both o if you want to know the real cause of the size differences then you should be able to work it out yourself. Start with each base image, then add the layers (or packages) individually and see what's different for each one.

Comment: The problem is, that it builds for 2 hours on my machine , so trying things with different dockerfile takes much time. I do not think that Jupyterlab takes over one 1GB more space, when not installed via a downloaded whl.

Comment: For each Dockerfile, you could run each ``pip install`` command as a separate RUN statement so they get a layer each, then compare the layer sizes and that should give you a good idea where the difference comes from. Use the ``docker history`` command on the built images to see the layer sizes.

Comment: I don't wanted to use much layers, but for testing this should be sufficient. Thank you for this advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue by removing "apt-get python3-dev", it was version 3.7.2. My baseimage is python 3.7.12 so maybe there was a conflict, I can not explain it.

The size of the image:

```
#docker image ls

REPOSITORY      TAG            IMAGE ID        CREATED             SIZE
jupyterlab      3.7.12_nodev   6112bcaff54d    17 hours ago        1.18GB
jupyterlab      3.9.9          1962a1eb6bff    2 days ago          1.12GB
```